# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'serie' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

I find the following error in this part of the project:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let date = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY')
    let fetch = await emailService.getUF(date)
    if (fetch) {
      this.setState({
        indicador: fetch.data.serie[0] ? fetch.data.serie[0].valor : 0
      })
    }
  }
```

In another project I run without problem, but in the master it does not. And it is exactly the same.

Comment: console.log(fetch). It doesn't have a data property. Where does this come from?

Comment: From an API that automatically gives me a price, getUF.

Comment: And do you see a data property? This error implies this property doesn't exist.